# HTML - bootstrap module wont load

Tags: html

Can you please see why my module does not load? The module is loaded under 
. When I call it in the third last column. When I test this code it wont work. Can you help me to see what went wrong? Thank you.

Stefan

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300'      rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
<body>


  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="project1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">My favorite App</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          hello how are you
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="title-logo" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
<h1 class="title-super text-thin">Jane Doette</h1>
<h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <hr>
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1140x350">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h2 class="text-muted">Featured Work</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" data-toggle="modal" data-target="project1">
        <h3 clss="text-uppercase">test</h3>
        <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <h3 clss="text-uppercase">Appify</h3>
        <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <h3 clss="text-uppercase">Appify</h3>
        <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read bootstrap documentation for model.
[Bootstrap documentation of model](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 0):

i think all you need is bootstrap.js, and make sure bootstrap path corect